# Understanding pandas apply looping behavior

Tags: python, pandas

*Edit: I reworded this question with a simpler case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60118136/take-a-cells-value-to-indicate-a-column-name-in-pandas).*

I still don't understand whether a series or a cell (eg. series[0,0]) is being passed around with `x` in the following line of code:

`df.apply(lambda x: "Y" if x > 0 else "N")`

I assume x is a single value, and this function is being performed piecewise.

However, this seems contradicted by my most recent apply attempt.

Right now I have this input dataframe:

```
      DBN Grade   3   4   5
0  01M015     3  30  44  15
1  01M015     4  30  44  15
2  01M015     5  30  44  15
3  01M020     3   0   0  26
4  01M020     4   0   0  26
5  01M020     5   0   0  26
```

I want to add a new column like so:

```
      DBN Grade   3   4   5 Enrollment?
0  01M015     3  30  44  15           Y
1  01M015     4  30  44  15           Y
2  01M015     5  30  44  15           Y
3  01M020     3   0   0  26           N
4  01M020     4   0   0  26           N
5  01M020     5   0   0  26           Y
```

However, the following code failed me:

```python
import pandas as pd

data={'DBN':['01M015','01M015','01M015','01M020','01M020','01M020'],
      'Grade':['3','4','5','3','4','5'],
      '3':['30','30','30','0','0','0'],
      '4':['44','44','44','0','0','0'],
      '5':['15','15','15','26','26','26']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Failure below!
df['Any Enrollment?'] = df.apply(lambda d: 'Y' if d[d['Grade']] != '0' else 'N')
```

**According to my understanding: If I had the capacity to inspect `d['Grade']` at this instance in a debugger, it should show '3'. So, `d[d['Grade']]` should resolve to `d['3']`, and this should work fine.**

However, I get `KeyError: 'Grade'` even though of course Grade exists.

Full code below, and my workaround.

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data={'DBN':['01M015','01M015','01M015','01M020','01M020','01M020'],
      'Grade':['3','4','5','3','4','5'],
      '3':['30','30','30','0','0','0'],
      '4':['44','44','44','0','0','0'],
      '5':['15','15','15','26','26','26']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# This line below doesn't work, though I think it should.
df['Any Enrollment?'] = df.apply(lambda d: 'Y' if d[d['Grade']] != '0' else 'N')

# This is my workaround.
def enrollment_bool(*args):
    for index in range(3,6):
        idx = index - 2
        if int(args[0]) == index:
            return "Y" if args[idx] != "0" else "N"

df['Enrollment?'] = np.vectorize(enrollment_bool)(df['Grade'],
                                                  df['3'],
                                                  df['4'],
                                                  df['5'])
```

**Please note my question is about the behavior of apply and pandas series vs cell in general, not other ways to solve this problem**

Thanks.

Comment: Please read docs on  [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) and [`DataFrame.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without specifying parameter `axis=` in the `.apply()` method, the default value `0` (i.e. `axis=0`) is used.

It means that `d` in your lambda function will obtain successively individual columns as a series objects.

So, let's start with the first column, the series `d = df["DBN"]`. The return value of your lambda function is

```
'Y' if d[d['Grade']] != '0' else 'N'
```

i. e.

```
'Y' if df["DBN"][df["DBN"]['Grade']] != '0' else 'N'
```

Now you can see, why you obtained the error

> ```
> KeyError: ('Grade', 'occurred at index DBN')
> ```

— from the part `df["DBN"]['Grade']` of it.

You probably wanted something as

```
df['Any Enrollment?'] = ['Y' if df['Grade'][i] != '0' else 'N' for i in df.index]
```

Comment: Thanks very much... I understand now.

Answer (score 1):

The `apply()` function takes a function as a parameter. It then loops across an `axis` (default 0, or down the rows) and applies that function to each element or cell. When called on a `dataframe`, the nature of the function determines whether the axis is treated together (e.g. `np.sum`), in which case a `series` is returned, or to apply the function to each element in the dataframe individually. When called on a series, it essentially loops through each "cell" or element in the series and "applies" or computes the function.

By passing the `lambda` function, you can create your own function. It basically just means to treat one element in the series as the variable `d` in your example. Then it will loop through the whole series and apply the same function to each cell individually.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to operate on every element on 'Grade' column, you should operate on Series containing 'Grade'.
Below code works for me :

```
df['Any Enrollment?'] = df['Grade'].apply(lambda d: 'Y' if d != '0' else 'N')
```

Comment: Thanks, this works fine. Though my question is really about why d[d['Grade']] couldn't resolve itself to d['3'] (in the example of the first computation of the for loop) and work out.