# Take a cell's value to indicate a column name in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Input

```
      DBN Grade   3   4   5
0  01M015     3  30  44  15
1  01M015     4  30  44  15
2  01M015     5  30  44  15
```

Desired Output

```
      DBN Grade   3   4   5  Enrollment
0  01M015     3  30  44  15  30
1  01M015     4  30  44  15  44
2  01M015     5  30  44  15  15
```

How would you create the Enrollment column?

Note that the column we seek for each record depends on the value at df['Grade'].

I've tried [variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60102536/understanding-pandas-apply-looping-behavior) of df[df['Grade']] so that I could find the column df['3'], but I haven't been successful.

Is there a way to do this simply?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data={'DBN':['01M015','01M015','01M015'],
      'Grade':['3','4','5'],
      '3':['30','30','30'],
      '4':['44','44','44'],
      '5':['15','15','15']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# This line below doesn't work: raises ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index
df['Enrollment'] = [df[c] if (df.loc[i,'Grade'] == c) else None for i in df.index for c
                    in df.columns]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set your index, and then use `lookup`:

```
df.set_index('Grade').lookup(df['Grade'], df['Grade'])
```

```
array(['30', '44', '15'], dtype=object)
```

---

You might run into some issues if your data is numeric (in your sample data it is all strings), requiring a cast to make the lookup succeed.

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data={'DBN':['01M015','01M015','01M015'],
      'Grade':['3','4','5'],
      '3':['30','30','30'],
      '4':['44','44','44'],
      '5':['15','15','15']}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
enrollmentList = []

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    enrollmentList.append(row[row["Grade"]])


df['Enrollment'] =  enrollmentList
```